# How to add a controller specific js file in application.html in Rail6 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Including .js files in Rails 6 using webpack

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if javascript_exists?(params[:controller]) %>


<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if javascript_exists?(params[:controller]) %>
```

`=> undefined method "javascript_exists?"`

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you should define `javascript_exists?` method defined in your `application.html` since you don't have method in the `application.html.erb` it is giving this error.

and other things to use the `webpack` you should have `javascript_pack_tag` instead of `javascript_include_tag`